# Mantener tamaño de DIV al colocar imagen SVG

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

estoy creando tabs en HTML Y CSS, a todos los tabs les di una proporción igual y todo llevan un icono en su interior (los iconos también son del mismo tamaño todos), el problema surge cuando uso un icono que por su geometría es mas largo que los demás provoca que el div se ensanche rompiendo la forma establecida.

Entonces me gustaría saber que propiedad usar para que el DIV mantenga su tamaño sin importar el tamaño del icono?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uso este código:

```
<div class="tab-icon"> <i class="fa fa-award"></i> </div> <div class="tab-title">highlights</div>
```

y el css:

```
.tab-icon {padding: 25px 30px;border: 1px solid #646464;margin-bottom: 20px;border radius: 50px;}.tab-icon i{font-size: 25px;color: #000;}
```

Fíjense que el primer tab y los 2 últimos están bien, mientras los demás se diferencia por el tamaño que deja de ser circular por el tamaño del icon.

Agradeceré algún tipo de ayuda.

Gracias.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Es importante siempre incluir un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Debes darle un tamaño al contenedor, de lo contrario, será este quien se adapte al contenido. Precisamente definiendo `width` y `height`.

Comment: @Mateo, gracias por tu ayuda, logre resolverlo con tu ayuda.